# python cookiecutter : Is there a way to make an input variable mandatory in cookiecutter?

Tags: cookiecutter

I have a cookiecuttern json like below

```
{
    "variable1": "Test variable 1 - mandatory",
    "variable2": "Test variable 2"
}
```

Is there any way to specify to the user of this cookiecuter that this field `variable1` is mandatory?  I dont want the user to proceed to entering a value for `variable2` without entering a value for `variable1`